# rails omniauth facebook extended permission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, facebook-graph-api, oauth-ruby, omniauth

I have read the omniauth oauth rdoc

```
  @consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(key, secret, {
    :site               => "http://term.ie",
    :scheme             => :header,
    :http_method        => :post,
    :request_token_path => "/oauth/example/request_token.php",
    :access_token_path  => "/oauth/example/access_token.php",
    :authorize_path     => "/oauth/example/authorize.php"
   })
```

there is no scope such as

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?
    client_id=...&
    redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/callback&
    scope=user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream
```

How do I add one? I am trying to overwrite oauth now ... do anyone got any better solution?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Put this in initializer

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :facebook , 'app' , 'secret' , {:scope => "manage_pages"}
end
```

If you are using more than one scope, it's comma delimited:

```
:scope => "offline_access, manage_pages"
```

Comment: if you are using more than one :scope, use a comma separeted string:
   :scope => "offline_access,manage_pages"

Comment: Documentation for provider setup here: http://rubydoc.info/gems/oa-oauth/0.2.6/OmniAuth/Strategies/Facebook Permissions/scope available listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/